# Please welcome your new Chemistry SE moderator Richard Terrett!

Tags: discussion, moderation

In order to help keep up with additional demand, [Richard Terrett](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/84/richard-terrett) has agreed to step up as an additional pro-tem moderator for the Chemistry SE community. Please give him a warm welcome as he steps into his new role in your service:

[image: profile for Richard Terrett at Chemistry Stack Exchange, Q&A for scientists, academics, teachers and students]

As a long term user with a great track record of friendly and helpful interactions, we're certain that he'll do a wonderful job. Welcome to the team, Richard!

Comment: Welcome Richard, and thanks for joining the team!

Comment: Hello all. I have been fairly passive on chem.se lately thanks to the chaos of school (and before that, like, a month of jury duty), but I'll endeavour to make time every day for moderation.

Comment: @RichardTerrett Welcome to the team! :D

Comment: @RichardTerrett Welcome, welcome.  Happy to have you aboard! :)

Comment: @RichardTerrett Welcome!

Comment: @RichardTerrett Welcome! :)