# What is the short form of Chemistry Stack Exchange: Chemistry.SE or Chemistry.SX?

Tags: discussion

In [this](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255/189) question the short form Chemistry.SE is used. However the TeX people use TeX.SX (see [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/6870)). Is it a matter of preference which one to use or is there an official form?

Comment: The TeX guys use it because it rhymes. I don't mind calling Chem.SE as Chex.SX, but I fear that we will become overrun with cereal-lovers in that case.

Answer (score 7):

If you'll permit me to use the statistics for usage on MSO, searching for "SE" (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=SE) yields 6182 results, and searching for SX only yields 34, most of which are regarding the TeX site.

I'm sure that everyone will know what you mean either way, but in terms of Stack Exchange colloquialisms, I think most people say Chemistry.SE.

Comment: vox populi vox dei :) Maybe the TeX people use the SX version so much because of the prominence of the letter X in the TeX world. I'll go with SE then. Thanks.

Comment: @Philipp No problem, thanks for checking and for your interest in the site in general!

Comment: It's chemistry, how could one not be interested! :) Ok, maybe physicists may disagree...